# Loop over and array and add a separator except for the last

Tags: loops, handlebars.js

Using Handlebarjs, I'd like to loop over an array, and display values, separated by a separator. It would be easy if the content I want to display wasn't a template too ;)

Here's my case :

```
accounts = [
     {'name': 'John', 'email': 'john@example.com'},
     {'name': 'Malcolm', 'email': 'malcolm@example.com'},
     {'name': 'David', 'email': 'david@example.com'}
];

{{#each accounts}}
    <a href="mailto:{{ email }}" title="Send an email to {{ name }}">{{ name }}</a>,
{{/each}}
```

The problem with this implementation is that I will have this output :

> John, Malcolm, David,

And I'd like it to be :

> John, Malcolm, David

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS pseudo class `:after`, together with content, to achieve the required "formatting".
(`:after` and content support in most browser today, and IE8+.)

For example:

HTML:

```
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxxx.com" title="Send an email to Foo">Foo1</a>
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxxx.com" title="Send an email to Foo">Foo2</a>
<a href="mailto:xxx@xxxx.com" title="Send an email to Foo">Foo3</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
  color: red;
}
a:after {
  content: ", ";
}
a:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

Result:

```
Foo1, Foo2, Foo3
```

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a new foreach helper that can do the trick :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('foreach', function (array, fn) {
    var total = array.length;
    var buffer = '';

    //Better performance: http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/2
    for (var i = 0, j = total; i < j; i++) {
        var item = array[i];

        // stick an index property onto the item, starting with 1, may make configurable later
        item['_index'] = i+1;
        item['_total'] = total;
        item['_isFirst'] = (i === 0);
        item['_isLast'] = (i === (total - 1));

        // show the inside of the block
        buffer += fn.fn(item);
    }

    // return the finished buffer
    return buffer;
});
```

And then :

```
{{#foreach accounts}}
    <a href="mailto:{{ email }}" title="Send an email to {{ name }}">{{ name }}</a>{{#unless _isLast}}, {{/unless}}
{{/foreach}}
```